# .co.uk site showing up for brand name searches from the US even when targeted .com site is available

Tags: seo, internationalization, geolocation, localization

We have a .co.uk and .com domains for our company. They are effectively the same site with the .co.uk being localised for the UK and .com being localised for the USA. There are some other differences too like product ranges not all being exact and blogs are mostly different too.

The sites are both setup in webmaster tools with the relevant regions confirmed. My issue is that the .co.uk (with higher page rank) still shows up over the .com when you search for our company name in the USA.

On Adwords we can set regions and they are honoured immediately, but it seems not the case with Google searches.

Comment: Surely you wouldn't want your .co.uk domain indexed at all in Google.com?

Comment: Its been a while since I've worked with internationalized sites using top level domains like that.   In my experience from five years ago, what you are doing should work just fine.  Maybe adding the hreflangs as suggested by the answers is needed these days.

Comment: Where is your .com site hosted?   If your .com is hosted in the in the UK, Google may be treating both your UK site and your .com site as somewhat targeted to the UK.  My experience was with sites hosted in the US.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate `hreflang` markup already? How are you searching "in the USA"? Do you literally have someone sat at a desk in the US?

Answer (score 3):

I think the proper heading looks something like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.co.uk" hreflang="en-gb" />
```

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en
(same link as provided by emirodgar)

Answer (score 2):

> You should use [hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) to geo locate each domain.

Quality links from those countries (local extensions and/or IP servers located there) would definitely help on local ranks.

Answer (score 1):

you can Do these things-

Google uses several factors to rank a site in a region. like as
Domain level extension - .com, co.in, co.uk etc.  country domains ranks in relative country higher. but for top-level domains like as .com Google looks on different factors...

your website language
your server location
access address
backlinks
users regions
keywords and much more. 
but these all are main factors.

make sure you are using USA English standards. and set language as other said... above.

can host that site from usa based hosting like as Bluehost, hostgator, siteground(i recommended )

Use more .us or other usa based domains to improve results in usa
use more terms USA or cities in your site content. 
like as bike resale in NY...

mainly these are the reasons that can affect your site results 99%...

Answer (score 0):

1 - <s>Most importantly; use correct language in your `<html>` tag to indicate what's the site language.</s>

2 - Add correct alternate tags as mentioned in previous answers. 
An alternative for this step is to using sitemap.xml.

Comment: Last I heard Google says they ignore the `lang` attribute on the `html` tag:  https://www.seroundtable.com/google-ignores-the-html-lang-attribute-22974.html

Comment: I see. Thanks for the correction. I stand corrected.